# How to do data manipulation using Index Match equivalent in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a DF(intents) with this structure:

```
    Com I1  I2  I3  I4  I5
0   A   1.0 0.3 0.2 0.8 0.5
1   B   0.9 0.9 0.1 0.5 0.1
```

And another DF(ls) like this

```
    LS Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
0  LS1   I1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  LS2  NaN   I2   I3  NaN  NaN
2  LS3   I1  NaN  NaN   I4  NaN
3  LS4  NaN   I2  NaN  NaN   I5
```

And I want to create the output with this structure

```
Com LS  I1  I2  I3  I4  I5
A   LS1 1.0 na  na  na  na
A   LS2 na  0.3 0.2 na  na
A   LS3 1   na  na  0.8 na
A   LS4 na  0.3 na  na  0.5
B   LS1 0.9 na  na  na  na
B   LS2 na  0.9 0.1 na  na
B   LS3 0.9 na  na  0.5 na
B   LS4 na  0.9 na  na  0.1
```

Currently, I am using excel to perform this operation but the data is supposed to grow huge and I need to use Python. I tried using

```
for loop and if-elif
```

but it looks nasty and highly inefficient. I could use some help do it efficiently in python. TIA

Answer (score 0):

First join both DataFrames by cross join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), filter columns with  regex starting by `|`+digit or `Val`+digit and because same length of filtered columns is possible replace `|` columns by `Val`s non missing values:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
col1 = df.filter(regex='^I\d').columns
col2 = df.filter(regex='^Var\d').columns

df[col1] = df[col1].mask(df[col2].isna().to_numpy())
df = df.drop(col2, axis=1)
df.insert(1, 'LS', df.pop('LS'))
print (df)
  Com   LS   I1   I2   I3   I4   I5
0   A  LS1  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   A  LS2  NaN  0.3  0.2  NaN  NaN
2   A  LS3  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.8  NaN
3   A  LS4  NaN  0.3  NaN  NaN  0.5
4   B  LS1  0.9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   B  LS2  NaN  0.9  0.1  NaN  NaN
6   B  LS3  0.9  NaN  NaN  0.5  NaN
7   B  LS4  NaN  0.9  NaN  NaN  0.1
```